# Reading filename to open file FORTRAN

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I would like to build a program in which a use is able to enter a filename and path to file. This should get stored into a `CHARACTER` variable, which can then be opened in the following way:

```
PROGRAM OPENFILE
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL DATA
CHARACTER FILENAME*100

PRINT *, 'Enter filename'
READ '(A)', FILENAME
OPEN(1, FILE=FILENAME, FORM='FORMATTED', STATUS='OLD')
DO
    READ(1, *, END=10) DATA
ENDDO
10 CONTINUE !Note: The label for CONTINUE is not in the correct position but put here for simplicity.

CLOSE(1)
END
```

The problem with this method is if `FILENAME` is much longer than 100 characters, then this method fails. Is there a way in which a character variable can be read without allocating `FILENAME` some ridiculously large amount of memory (i.e. allocate the exact amount required based on the input)?

I am quite new to working in this programming language, and any help would be appreciated

Note: If there is a FORTRAN 77 solution to this problem, I'd like this as I have been tasked to write a programme in 77, and I want to try to stick to the brief given to me, where possible. If this is unreasonable, then I am happy to receive FORTRAN 90/95 solutions too.

Comment: A dynamic length for input with a read statement is quite tricky (and other questions here partly address some aspects), but note that OS limits for length of paths are generally not "ridiculously large" so a static length could be feasible.

Comment: You failed to identify which operating system you are using.  Most systems define a PATH_MAX or similar constant in one of its C header files.  For example, on FreeBSD sys/syslimits.h has PATH_MAX set to 1024.

Comment: Note your program as written is not Fortran77 but uses a number of Fortran90 and later features, I can see 3 without trying very hard. I also think that requiring anything in Fortran77 over the last fifteen or so years is totally unreasonable.

Comment: This looks like homework assignment #2. In assignment #1 hello world provided examples of print statement to debug assignment #2.